# How can I send a fax with Windows 7 connected on DSL?

Tags: windows-7, fax

I have a computer with **Windows 7**.

It is connected to the Internet via a **router** and **DSL**.

What I have found on the Internet regarding this seems to assume I have my **phone** somehow connected to my computer. I live in **Germany** and the phone is plugged into completely **different box** and so has nothing to do with the computer at this point.

**How can I simply write a Word document (Office 2003 and Office 2010 beta) and send it to a fax number?** e.g. are there any online services that do this, either free or payable via PayPal?

Answer (score 1):

Since I do not have a phone line anymore I use [faxzero](http://faxzero.com/) when I need to send a fax. Although there are a few draw backs

> Ad on the cover page
>
> Fax 1 document - maximum 3 pages
>
> Maximum 2 free faxes per day

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. You obtain a DSL line filter suitable for connecting a standard voice
   telephone to the DSL line, then connect an analog fax modem to the line
   through the line filter.
2. Use the Internet. See this extensive coverage:
   [FAQ: How can I send a fax from the Internet?](http://www.savetz.com/fax/)