# Faxing software

Tags: fax, efax

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Fax software for Windows Vista Home Premium](https://superuser.com/questions/47416/fax-software-for-windows-vista-home-premium)
>   [fax for linux desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/10397/fax-for-linux-desktop)
>   [How can I send a fax with Windows 7 connected on DSL?](https://superuser.com/questions/86758/how-can-i-send-a-fax-with-windows-7-connected-on-dsl)

Is there any software which can mimic a physical fax machine? I have a fax modem installed in my PC.

Comment: There are many (near) duplicates of your question. Please read these (search for "fax"), then ask a more specific question. E.g. http://superuser.com/questions/10397/fax-for-linux-desktop , http://superuser.com/questions/86758/how-can-i-send-a-fax-with-windows-7-connected-on-dsl

Comment: But above given links are not fulfilling my requirement !!

Comment: What's the OS​?

Comment: windows: http://superuser.com/questions/47416/fax-software-for-windows-vista-home-premium

Comment: If there is a reason the other questions don't answer yours, could you specify why they didn't work and what you tried to solve it yourself. Else this IS a duplicate

Comment: @Mr-Right: This is a duplicate question as it currently stands. We need more information before your question can become unique. I will re-open this question once you explain exactly what you need and maybe why the other answers in the other questions do not meet your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [EssentialFax](http://www.essentialfax.com/). It has a nice set of features and a decent price ($30). You can also try it for 30 days before buying...